# How to scale with docker-compose with an API gateway

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, rasa

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to do this!

So I'm developing a multilingual chatbot solution. I have 4 languages and each language is a different bot (docker container), I also have a DB container that's connected to all 4 docker containers. (Running on an Ubuntu EC2 AWS instance).

When a user sends a message, it goes into the "API Gateway" a simple flask application that takes the message input, uses language detection and then "chooses" the right API, something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from langdetect import detect 



def bot_response(message,url,user=""):
    """ 
        Gets chatbot response from Rasa Server API

        Parameters:                     # container URL # 
            url(str): URL link ie http://project_rasa_1:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook
            message(str): User's message 
            user(str): user (optional)
        Returns:
            (request) : response object from rasa 
    """

    data = {"sender": user, "message": message }
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    r = requests.post(url, data = json_data)

    return r


URL_ENGLISH = "http://project_rasa_1:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook"
URL_SPANISH = "http://project_rasa-es_1:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook"
URL_CHINESE = "http://project_rasa-zh_1:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook"
URL_ARABIC = "http://project_rasa-ar_1:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook"

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class ReceiveMessage(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

    def post(self):
        
        message = request.json['message']
        lang = detect(lang) # "en" "es" ....
        if lang == "en":
            rasa_response =bot_response(message,URL_ENGLISH,user="")
        
        elif lang == "es":
            rasa_response =bot_response(message,URL_SPANISH,user="")

        elif lang == "ar":
            rasa_response =bot_response(message,URL_ARABIC,user="")
        
        elif lang == "ZH":
            rasa_response =bot_response(message,URL_CHINESE,user="")

        return rasa_response


api.add_resource(ReceiveMessage, '/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=7000)
```

So I tie everything with a docker-compose.yml file (so that the API can call the URL's by the container name.

```
version: '3'
services:
  rasa:
    image: rasa/rasa:latest-full
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./rasa-en:/app
    command:
      - run
      - --debug


  
  rasa-ar:
    image: rasa/rasa:latest-full
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./rasa-ar:/app
    command:
      - run
      - --debug



  rasa-es:
    image: rasa-spacy-es:1.11
    user: root

    volumes:
      - ./rasa-es:/app
    command:
      - run 
      - --debug

        
  rasa-zh:
    image: rasa/rasa:latest-full
    user: root

    volumes:
      - ./rasa-zh:/app
    command:
      - run 
      - --debug


  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always

    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"



  flask:
    image: flask-gate:3.2.1
    environment:
      PYTHONIOENCODING: utf-8

    ports: 
      - "7000:7000"
```

I wanted to scale up, let's say I want 3 bots for english. Normally I'd use:

`docker-compose scale rasa=4`

But since I hardcoded the container URL's, they are worthless! How can I scale and do a load balancer inside the api ? The problem is that I need the API to detect the language!

Any suggestion is welcomed, or any tip/direction would be great! I don't mind trying it from scratch, I'm not at all tied to this solution! Any other suggestions with anyother technologies are welcomed!

Sorry for the long post

Best Jose

Answer (score -1):

There's a Rasa Kubernetes install that addresses this. It is described [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/installation-and-setup/openshift-kubernetes/).

You could run the English bot under this configuration to handle scaling.

Greg

Comment: That's using Rasa X, I'm not using it, nor do I want to